# JSON Array Retrofit and display it on a recyclerview Android Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, arraylist

I'm trying to implement a @GET request but I'm getting a null response. I'm familiar with implementing a response body with the following

```
"billers": [
    {
        "name": "Biller full name",
        "slug": "biller-short-name",
        "fields": {
            "FieldName": {
                "type": "can be textfield, date, selectable or hidden",
                "required": true,
                "placeholder": "This is a field",
                "defaultValue": "value1"
                "regex": "only appears if the type is textfield e.g. ^[-a-zA-Z .]{1,100}$",
                "dateFormat": "only appears if type is date e.g. yyyy-MM-dd",
                "values": [
                    "value1": "only appears if type is selectable",
                    "value2": "value 2"
                ]
            }
        }
]
```

but this is my first time implementing a response like this

```
[
{
    "name": "Category full name",
    "slug": "category-short-name",
    "iconUrl": {
      "android": {
        "xhdpi": "xhdpi category icon url",
        "mdpi": "mdpi category icon url",
        "hdpi": "hdpi category icon url"
      },
      "ios": {
        "3x": "3x biller icon url",
        "retina": "retina biller icon url",
        "nonRetina": "non-retina icon image url"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Here are my classes

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is my error, I get a 200 calling the api, but when I try to display it on a recyclerview, it says that the response is null

[image]

Comment: have you tried to log what are you getting in the response?

Comment: attach the code not the screen shot

Answer (score 0):

You do not show how are you transforming the response to your model. From the second response you can see that your response is a list of `PayBillsCategoryModel`

For example with Gson you have something like this:

```
data class PayBillsCategoryModel(
    @SerializedName("name ") val name: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("name ") val slug: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("name ") val iconUrl: IconUrl? = null
)


data class IconUrl(
    @SerializedName("android") val android: Android? = null,
    @SerializedName("ios") val ios: Ios? = null
)

data class Android(
    @SerializedName("xhdpi") val xhdpi: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("mdpi") val mdpi: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("hdpi") val hdpi: String? = null,
)

data class Ios(
    @SerializedName("3x") val x3: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("retina") val retina: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("nonRetina") val nonRetina: String? = null
)
```

So after api call your response is

```
 data class Response(val payBillsList: ArrayList<PayBillsCategoryModel>)
```

and you need to pass this list to your adapter

```
adapter.setData(payBillList)
```